# Pandas Dataframe to Dataframe Assignment Not Aligning and Producing NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign the values of one Pandas dataframe to another dataframe.  However, the assignment results are not behaving as I expected and I'm not sure why.  I have a workaround, however, I don't understand why this workaround is necessary or whether it is a preferred workaround.

I set up my data like this:

```
d1 = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'col2': ['a','ERROR','ERROR','ERROR', 'e']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = {'col3': ['b','c','d']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
bad = (df1['col2'] == 'ERROR')
```

This is what I tried (but it does not work as I expected):

```
df1.loc[bad,'col2'] = df2.loc[:,'col3']
print(df1)

   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    c
2     3    d
3     4  NaN
4     5    e
```

However, if I change the code to the following, then it does work:

```
df1.loc[bad,'col2'] = df2.loc[:,'col3'].values
print(df1)

   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
4     5    e
```

Comment: because `df2.loc[:,'col3']` has an index of [0, 1, 2], and the assignment will be aligned to df1 according to those positions.

Comment: @coldspeed, is my workaround the preferred workaround or is there a better way of solving the problem?

Comment: No, I think that is the most painless way of doing it. Either that, or assign a list `df2.loc[:,'col3'].tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining `@coldspeed` comment.

Try this:

```
df1.loc[bad, 'col2']
```

which gives you

```
1    ERROR
2    ERROR
3    ERROR
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

As you can observe above data has index 1,2 and 3. Now check df2 index

```
    col3
0   b
1   c
2   d
```

So when you replace using `df1.loc[bad,'col2'] = df2.loc[:,'col3']` only second and third index gets the values. However, when you use `values` you are proceeding correctly because that forms a numpy array as can be verified from `type(df2.col3.values)` or a python list using `type(df2.col3.tolist())`. Both of them are acceptable.